# Is there any way to find a number N if it's Carmichael function is given.

Tags: carmichael-function

I know to find the Carmichael function [ C() ] of a given no. But I want to know if there is any method or shortcut to find a number N if it's C() is given.

Answer (score -3):

PARI/GP examples:

n-Carmichael <=> B(n)=eulerphi(n),

where B(n)=PRODUCT(p: p-1|n-1, where p|n and p-Prime)

It's analog for:
 n-Prime<=> n-1=eulerphi(n)

Your method:
  n-Carmichael <=> C(n)|n-1

where:
  C(n)=znstar(n)[2][1]