# There are infinitely many $n$ such that $\lambda(n) = k$?

Tags: number-theory, carmichael-function

There are infinitely many $n$ such that $\lambda(n) = k$ ([Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function))?

For example: $k = 4$.

How efficiently we can generate all $n$ for which $\lambda(n) = 4$?

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2088516/is-there-any-way-to-find-a-number-n-if-its-carmichael-function-is-given

Comment: Thanks! And the first (title) question? (It is infinite?)

Comment: No, definitely not infinite. For large enough $n$ we can be sure that $\lambda(n)>k$.